# php array_rand() with multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have an array that relates mp3 files and their respective lengths in seconds

```
$playlist = array(  array("song" => "01.mp3","min" => "91"),
                   array("song" => "02.mp3","min" => "101"),
                   array("song" => "03.mp3","min" => "143"),
                   array("song" => "04.mp3","min" => "143"),
                   array("song" => "05.mp3","min" => "151")
            );
```

The I pluck a song from the playlist with `array_rand()`...

```
$song = $playlist[array_rand($playlist)];
```

Then, later on, I access the values from that array...

```
echo $song['song'];

//Then somewhere else...

echo $song['min'];
```

My question is, each time I request `$song`, is it going to produce a random result, or does it only produce a random result once per page load? (ie, once $song is defined,  it's defined for good.)  ...I'm hoping it's the latter.

Comment: `$song` is assigned only at creation, it will remain the same for the remainder of that request / the variables lifetime.

Comment: $song value  intialize on on page load, not each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, each time I request $song, is it going to produce a random result, or does it only produce a random result once per page load?

No, it won't. It will *produce* a random result every time you call the `array_rand` function. If you call it once per page load then yes, it will produce only one random result every time a page is loaded.

---

In general every time you *access* a variable you are most likely not going to change it in that specific line. In particular, simplifying your example (`rand` picks a number from the minimum to the maximum specified):

```
$x = rand(0, 9);
```

if a number, let's say `7`, is picked then multiple accesses to `$x` will not change its value. Only an explicit `$x = y` assignment (or passing it to a class or function that has *side effect* on it) will possibly change its value.

Considering `7` to be picked from `rand`:

```
echo $x;
echo $x;
echo $x;
```

will print `777`.